# Можно ли изменить имя телеграм бота. PYTHON

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Можно ли как-то изменить имя бота в телеграм не через ботфазера, а через код на Python?

Comment: написать юзербота, который напишет ботфазеру. А зачем?

Comment: @ClarkDevlin Хотелось бы чтобы пользователь смог менять имя) Бот предназначается в основном для одного человека

Comment: Ну библиотека telethon в помощь, там можно написать юзербота, который будет писать ботфазеру, но оно того не стоит

Comment: @ClarkDevlin Спасибо вам!